# gdb - searching for pointers to a given memory region

Tags: debugging, gdb, exploit

Let's suppose there is a memory region that is m'mapped in memory, we need to find its address (which randomly changes, because of ASLR) by following a pointer path, basically, I'm trying to find a possibly multilevel pointer that leads to any address in that memory region, and that starts from an address in a memory region I choose, is that possible to do with gdb? I've checked out the popular gdb extensions (peda, pwndbg), but didn't find such a feature, if there is no existing implementation, any tips on how to optimize the search? Kind of like the Pointer Scanner of Cheat Engine, pointers can also have offsets (for example : main_module+3170 -> 0x7fff42dc7220 ; 0x7fff42dc7220+10 -> 0x7ff464213460 ; 0x7ff464213460 -> address wanted).

This would be useful for example in a context where we have a write-what-where condition (we can write or read anywhere in memory), and we need to defeat ASLR to find interesting memory regions (for example, JIT buffers in browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is now more than 4 years old, but: We created a gdb extension that can do just that. It's available here: https://github.com/ChaChaNop-Slide/ptrfind